# How to use multiple options with the .format() function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I read the section about .format() function in the Python3.3 documentation and did some online research, but unfortunately I only find examples and explanations for "single" options.

Here is an example:

- printing right aligned

`>>> print("this is a {:>30}  test ".format(2.345345345345))`

```
this is a                 2.345345345345  test
```

- printing only  2 digits after the decimal point

`>>> print("this is a {:.2f}  test ".format(2.345345345345))`

```
this is a 2.35  test
```

But how would I do both at once? I already tried various variation, but unfortunately without success. Anyone knows the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
print("this is a {:>30.2f} test ".format(2.345345345345))
```

When in doubt, try the obvious solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
print("this is a {:>30.2f} test ".format(2.345345345345))
```